# Toast notification in WPF: ToastNotificationManager.History throws an exception win10

Tags: c#, wpf

With a lot of limitations, I manage to pop toast notifications in WPF thanks to instructions given below.

https://www.michaelcrump.net/pop-toast-notification-in-wpf/

Unfortunately, I didn't proceed very much with that with extending the code.
I tried to get the history of the Notifications

```
       ToastNotificationManager.History.GetHistory();
```

But it keeps throwing an exception as follow:

```
       Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490);
```

Can you please give me some hint?

Regards, 
Reza

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link and scroll right to the bottom.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/modernize-wpf-tutorial-4

Notice the error code is the same as yours.

As it says, this is because you haven't registered a package identity for your app.

If I recall correctly, once you register an identity then you only get authority to do things with notifications your app raised.

Comment: Hi Andy
Thank you for your comment. 
I guess there should a different reason for that.
Because if I don't specify the "sender" in the following code it will throw the exception your mentioned.

`ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(Sender).Show(notifier);`

Comment: Same problem. You haven't registered a package id for your app.  Sender (applicationID) is the package identity to override the current package id.  No parameter uses whatever identity you registered for the running package.